# QTKit strange error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, qtkit

just simple peace of code (file 1.mp3 clicked and playing as well in iTunes) :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

NSError *outError = nil;
QTMovie *newMovie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/Alex/1.mp3"] error:&outError];
if (newMovie) {
    //[newMovie setAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieEditableAttribute];

    [self setMovie:newMovie];
}
[movie play];
```

give me error

- Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
  Code=-2000 UserInfo=0x2004a6de0 "A
  necessary data reference could not be
  resolved."

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
[movie play];
```

to

```
[movie autoplay];
```

might help you. `QTMovie` loads the data in the background, so asking it to play right after it's created might be too quick for the `QTMovie` to really play the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `file:`-based `NSURL` using `fileURLWithPath:`, not `URLWithString:`. `URLWithString:` is meant for URLs like `http:`, etc.

Try:

```
QTMovie *newMovie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:
   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Alex/1.mp3"] error:&outError];
```