# How do I load multiple QTMovie objects and then choose which to play?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quicktime

I am new to working with Objective-C and Cocoa.

I have followed the sample code for playing a movie with Quicktime that is on [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MyMediaPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html). I am wondering how to expand it so that I can load multiple `QTMovie`s at the beginning of the program, and then play each of them when requested with minimal latency.

My initial strategy was to create a class that holds a `QTMovie` object and the methods for loading and playing it. Then in my main class I'd have a list of these `MovieContainer` objects.

When I try implementing this, I get a `QTMovieLoadStateError` during the loading of each `QTMovie` with the error message

```
Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2098 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(OSStatus error -2098.)" (component is not thread-safe)
```

Am I going in completely the wrong direction, or am I merely missing a few lines of code that would make this "thread-safe"?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before working with QTMovie objects in a background (non-main) thread you need to call:

```
[QTMovie enterQTKitOnThread]
```

or

```
[QTMovie enterQTKitOnThreadDisablingThreadSafetyProtection]
```

Which one to choose would depend on the codec of your movie file. The second variant will allow non-thread-safe components; for some rare codecs this would be the only way.

The call must be paired with:

```
[QTMovie exitQTKitOnThread]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That did eliminate the thread error, but now I get `A necessary data reference could not be resolved.`.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582274/qtkit-strange-error with the same error, but the solution does not help. I only see these errors when I check the value of `QTMovieLoadStateAttribute` for `QTMovieLoadStateError`.

Comment: The movie may take some time to load. You need to check attributeForKey:`QTMovieLoadStateAttribute` and wait until it equals `QTMovieLoadStateComplete`. For example `while ([[movie attributeForKey:QTMovieLoadStateAttribute] longValue] != QTMovieLoadStateComplete)
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}`